# enum with rawValue and agument in cases

Tags: swift, enums, arguments, raw-types

I just defined my enum and to each case some arguments are assigned however I wonder why can't I use the rawValue feature anymore

```
enum test : Int {
    case danial (Int, Double, String)
    case weiLiang(Int, String)
    case KS(Int, String)
    case Eugin(Int, Double, String)
    case sina(Int, Double, String)
}
```

Comment: Enums with raw types can not have cases with arguments - is the error compiler rightly throws...

Comment: rawValue is a unique identifier for enum case and enum gets a free  init with rawValue. When you use associated values, enumCase(someValue) and enumCase(anotherValue) are not the same. By the way enums can be recursive i.e. have itself as associated values and so can have different internal structure with this feature.